# Keycloak - What is the best way to get User's role

Tags: keycloak

Hi I'm using Keycloak and I would like to know what is the best way to get User Role. I'm using a SPA written in ReactJS and it needs to know the user's role. Is there a Keycloak API to get this? or should I get it from the JWT token. Either way, what is the option that I should go with. Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify if an application gateway is used or SPA connects to Keycloak directly?

Comment: @user1264304 Yes I'm using Kong and Keycloak isn't behind the gateway. But other Springboot services are. And yes the SPA has the keycloak-js library implemented in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you assigned role to a user, then this role is a claim inside JWT access token provided by Keycloak.

A user would have to be authenticated before seeing some application content.

After successful authentication, access token would be given to client (can be application gateway or ui application) and then role can be extracted from it and used.

Comment: How the role can be extracted from the JWT Access token?

Comment: have a look at the token contents

Comment: It is wrong, roles isn't part of the standard claims
https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims

Answer (score 7):

Yes, rest API is there to get user roles

```
GET /auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{user-uuid}/role-mappings/clients/{client-uuid}
```

you can find all the rest api of keycloak here:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html